# What's the difference between ? and None in tensor shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

This is the case of shape *(?)*

```
effnet_layers =  effnet.EfficientNetB0(input_shape=(row,col, sat_channel), weights=None, include_top=False)(sat_inputs)
print("effnet_layers shape",effnet_layers.shape)
```

result is **effnet_layers shape (?, 2, 2, 1280)**

And this is the case of shape *(None)*

```
for i in range(sat_in_len_max*sat_in_dim):
    sat_inputs = Input(shape=(row,col, sat_channel))
    sat_layer = Conv2D(c1, (5, 5))(sat_inputs)
    sat_layer = ReLU()(sat_layer)
    sat_layer = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(sat_layer)
    sat_layer = Conv2D(c2, (7, 7))(sat_layer)
    sat_layer = ReLU()(sat_layer)
    sat_layer = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))(sat_layer)
    print("after conv:", sat_layer.shape)
    sat_layer = Flatten()(sat_layer)
    print("after flatten:", sat_layer.shape)
    sat_layer = Reshape((1, sat_layer.shape[1]))(sat_layer)
```

The result is **after conv: (None, 6, 6, 32)
after flatten: (None, 1152)**

both input shape is same as (40, 40, 1)

Comment: This doesn't make sense. In Keras, [EfficientNetB0](https://keras.io/api/applications/efficientnet/) should return a Keras model, which does not have a `.shape` attribute. Can you clarify where did you call your EficientNetB0 model?

Comment: Shape `None` in your second example is simply the `batch_size`. In Keras, setting `batch_size` to `None` means that it can accept any value

Comment: `None` is used by python objects, disconnected from the TF graph. This means that `None` shapes cannot be used in graph mode execution (and in some cases, can give null gradients in eager mode). `?` indicates tensorflow placeholders that have the graph built with unknown dimension. `?` cannot be used for pythonic calculations, and will mostly be detached and converted to `None` implicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. By the way, I used this package 'efficientnet 1.1.1' and used this code 'import efficientnet.keras as effnet' to import.